# Execute glue job from codecommit repository from another glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have one code of the aws glue artifact stored in aws codecommit and needed execute him from the another glue job. It's possible make this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CI/CD setup (AWS CodePipeline or Jenkins on EC2) to fetch artifacts from AWS CodeCommit and store in S3 storage and then launch glue job